# Cannot find missing ) in my code that shows in Chrome Console

Tags: google-chrome, arguments

[Testing Youtube Popup](https://codepen.io/kwmatan/pen/dXQvQo)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function goclicky(meh)
{
    var x = screen.width/2 - 700/2;
    var y = screen.height/2 - 450/2;
    window.open(meh.href, 'sharegplus''height=640,width=800,left='+x+',top='+y, 'toolbar=no' 'menubar=no');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q96WHt9s_1M" onclick="goclicky(this); return false;" target="_blank">Check out my new video Blind!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The Chrome Console shows "Uncaught Syntax Error: missing ) after argument list.

I know chrome is incredibly forgiving but as a no0b I'd like to know which it is.  This is my first try at a new popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a couple commas in your `window.open()`. It should read:

```
window.open(meh.href, 'sharegplus',
    'height=640,width=800,left='+x+',top='+y, 'toolbar=no', 'menubar=no');
```

Comment: Fixed.  Thank you!  Not sure how to mark this solved